Oracle Revoke Invalid Grants
I'm currently in the process of migrating a database, and dropping several schemas in the move.
The schemas I'm excluding have grants on some of the schemas that are included. Like grant update on IncludedSchema.ATable to ExcludedSchema.
It doesn't appear possible to exclude these grants from the export. That was probably a choice made by the datapump devs (including all grants on the schema vs. grants given to the schema).
I want to clean these up after the migration. Is there an easy way to do that? Does anyone have a script to find and revoke grants given to grantees that do not exist?

is it necessary? you can allow datapump to emit errors when those grants fail and it shouldn't prevent you from accomplishing your migration. there isn't anything left behind to clean up... such grants would not have succeeded so don't need to be revoked.

@PaulW I think you're right. I forgot that the schemas I'm excluding were created on the target server during earlier failed migration tests. So the grant statements weren't failing on subsequent tests. It will make for a noisy import log but otherwise should be fine.
